# Gluon Client Plugin android tools missing

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafx-11

I'm starting to use Gluon Client Graalvm.

Thats working:

- Run my Mobileapplication on Host (Linux)
- Build android target

But when I want to package it, it doesnt find the android-tools. My `ANDROID_SDK` is pointing to the sdk. What could be the problem? `The Android SDK is required to build applications for the android platform. The Android SDK will be downloaded automatically by the client plugin and configured with the required packages.` is not working...

Thats my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<properties>
    <mainClassName>com.wulfsystems.fcbinside.FCBinsideApp</mainClassName>
    <javafx>11.0.2</javafx>
    <attach.version>4.0.6</attach.version>
</properties>


<groupId>com.wulfsystems.fcbinside</groupId>
<artifactId>App</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>


<dependencies>
    <!-- JAVAFX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gluon  Attaach-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>display</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>util</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gluonhq/charm-glisten -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <graalvmHome>/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/graalvm-svm-linux-20.1.0-ea+26</graalvmHome>
                <target>android</target>
                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Gluon</id>
        <url>http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>gluon-releases</id>
        <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And my error log:

> [Di. Apr. 21 12:59:09 MESZ 2020][INFORMATION] Default Android resources generated in /home/wulf/IdeaProjects/FCBinsideApp/target/client/aarch64-android/gensrc/android.
>   Consider copying them to /home/wulf/IdeaProjects/FCBinsideApp/src/android before performing any modification
>   com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AndroidTargetConfiguration$BuildToolNotFoundException: Android build tools not found. Please install it and try again.
>       at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AndroidTargetConfiguration.findLatestBuildTool(AndroidTargetConfiguration.java:573)
>       at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AndroidTargetConfiguration.packageApp(AndroidTargetConfiguration.java:153)
>       at com.gluonhq.substrate.SubstrateDispatcher.nativePackage(SubstrateDispatcher.java:378)
>       at com.gluonhq.NativePackageMojo.execute(NativePackageMojo.java:48)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)

Comment: Can you try the fix mentioned [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/issues/71#issuecomment-613470488)?

Comment: @JoséPereda Thx. It worked good.